# Visual studio 2013 does build but do not run the solution

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on my school project and hit on problem with Visual studio 2013...
I created a clr project and added windows form and entry point as supposed but after building the project successfully it doesn't run it and gives me an error "system cannot find the file specified"... but when I try to run currently built .exe it works perfectly...

Any idea why the debugger cannot open the file?

Comment: have you tried restarting VS? or your computer?

Comment: yes didn't help... cannot even run my older projects...

Comment: I recently reinstaled my whole computer including visual studio and since then having this problem... not even running visual as admin helps so it shouldn't be case of unauthorized access to file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't actually know what was the problem but reinstalling VS13 to my C: drive helped... don't know if it was just reinstalling or choosing another partition or what but used the same iso from dreamspark booth times...

Answer (score 1):

Just right click on Win Form project then click Debug -> Step into new instance. That's it